# AWS VPC EC2 connectivity within same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud, vpc

Question is really simple and I cannot find 100% clarification in AWS documentation. Are EC2 instances within the same subnet in AWS connected on layer 2 or layer 3?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/amazon-vpc-for-on-premises-network-engineers-part-one/

Comment: Ye I saw that and sentence "Subnets can be very large on AWS, since broadcast traffic is eliminated (see the “Routing and Switching” section later in this blog post for details)." So it looks more like layer 3 as in layer 2 broadcast should be possible but still it's not like 100% clarification.

Comment: VPC supports neither multicast nor broadcast.

Comment: AWS VPCs are not quite the same as a normal network because they are virtualized and encapsulated within a physical network, much like VMWare networking is virtualized. Is there a particular reason you are asking this question?